# Transform an array of Objects to a new set of Object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

This question has been asked in many different forms, but I haven't been able to piece it all together to achieve the outcome I'm looking for. So, sorry for duplicating the duplicates...

What I'm wanting to do is take an Array like this:

```
[
  0: { 
       2014: "6", 
       2015: "19",
       2016: "3",
       2017: "12",
       Name: "Jerry"
     },
  1: { 
       2014: "16", 
       2015: "9",
       2016: "",
       2017: "16",
       Name: "Bill"
     },
  2: { 
       2014: "", 
       2015: "2",
       2016: "43",
       2017: "7",
       Name: "Grace"
     }
]
```

Into something like this:

```
{
    "years": {
        "2014": {
            "Jerry": 6,
            "Bill": 16,
            "Grace": ""
        },
        "2015": {
            "Jerry": 19,
            "Bill": 9,
            "Grace": 2
        },
        "2016": {
            "Jerry": 3,
            "Bill": "",
            "Grace": 43
        },
        "2017": {
            "Jerry": 12,
            "Bill": 16,
            "Grace": 7
        }
    }
}
```

Bit of Code I still have after trying stuff, deleting, repeat, repeat...:

FYI - data is from CSV file being loaded from D3.js csv()

```
let loadData = () => {
    return d3.csv(dataFile, function cb (err, d) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return d;
    });
};

loadData().get((err, n) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    let years = [];

    years.push(Object.keys(n[0]));

    years = _.flatten(years);
    years.splice(-1, 1);


    console.log(n[0]);

    n.map((x) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(x[0]));
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: The code I have is a load of a crap. I have been flailing about with this for a while now and finally gave in. After trying this, deleting that, trying something else, deleting those things, I literally have nothing to provide... :(

Comment: @FernandoVega If your code is crap, we can help you with more that just giving solution. But until you share effort, please do not expect any answers

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Concerning first array, shouldn´t be it an object rather then array?

Comment: Sorry folks! I've updated question to include my crap!

Comment: @FernandoVega You do not need to apologies to anyone. Just remember the importance of sharing effort. That will enable us to see your mistake and could help you with solving your problem along with better conventions/approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "reduce" to achieve this.

```js
var data = [{
  2014: "6",
  2015: "19",
  2016: "3",
  2017: "12",
  Name: "Jerry"
}, {
  2014: "16",
  2015: "9",
  2016: "",
  2017: "16",
  Name: "Bill"
}, {
  2014: "",
  2015: "2",
  2016: "43",
  2017: "7",
  Name: "Grace"
}];

data = data.reduce(function(pre, v) {

  for (var i in v) {
    if (i === 'Name') {
      continue;
    }
    if (!pre[i]) {
      pre[i] = {};
    };

    pre[i][v.Name] = v[i];

  }
  return pre;
}, {});
data = {
  years: data
};
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterating the array and the keys and build a new object.

```js
var data = [{ 2014: "6", 2015: "19", 2016: "3", 2017: "12", Name: "Jerry" }, { 2014: "16", 2015: "9", 2016: "", 2017: "16", Name: "Bill" }, { 2014: "", 2015: "2", 2016: "43", 2017: "7", Name: "Grace" }],
    grouped = { years: {} };

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'Name') {
            grouped.years[k] = grouped.years[k] || {};
            grouped.years[k][o.Name] = o[k];
        }
    });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please let OP share effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to build object and inside you can use `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` loop to add object for each year.

```js
var arr = [{"2014":"6","2015":"19","2016":"3","2017":"12","Name":"Jerry"},{"2014":"16","2015":"9","2016":"","2017":"16","Name":"Bill"},{"2014":"","2015":"2","2016":"43","2017":"7","Name":"Grace"}]

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(e) {
    if(!r.years[e]  && e != 'Name') r.years[e] = {}
    Object.assign(r.years[e] || {}, {[o.Name]: o[e]})
  })
  return r;
}, {years: {}})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` method for this scenario. First parameter to this method is a reducer and the second one is initial value.

```js
var input = [{
    2014: "6",
    2015: "19",
    2016: "3",
    2017: "12",
    Name: "Jerry"
  },
  {
    2014: "16",
    2015: "9",
    2016: "",
    2017: "16",
    Name: "Bill"
  },
  {
    2014: "",
    2015: "2",
    2016: "43",
    2017: "7",
    Name: "Grace"
  }
];

var output = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  for (var k in b) {
    if (k !== 'Name') {
      a.year[k] = a.year[k] || {};
      a.year[k][b.Name] = b[k];
    }
  }
  return a;
}, {
  years: {}
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` is not mandatory. For instance:

```
let result = { years : {} };
for (let record of input) {
    for (let key in record) {
        if (key == 'Name') continue;
        result.years[key] = result.years[key] || {};
        result.years[key][record.Name] = record[key];
    }
}
```